# Where do I put back-end service proxies in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-organization

My controller needs to talk to a back-end service via HTTParty.  Where would you put that service proxy class?

I was thinking I would create an /app/services folder for this, but I was wondering if there was something more idiomatically appropriate?

Comment: I can't help but think, after only reading the headline, that the answer would be, "on the back-end".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put mine in `app/models`, but `app/services` seems appropriate as well if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I would store it within the `lib` folder (possibly in `lib/services` ?) and then require it where necessary.

I believe this would be the "Rails place" to store it...

Comment: I believe this is more appropriate than in app/services.